# Dynamic insertion in the database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning to program in php and I came across a problem that I can not solve.
Basically I have to insert a form into the database, with a dynamic part (in the sense that the user can decide how many fields to insert).
This form will go to populate two Tables: Prenotazione, Personale.
As for the first table, it is populated correctly. The second one is not, that is, only the name is inserted and not the rest. How can I proceed according to you? Where was I wrong? Thank you so much for your help and for your time.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Prenotazione Videoconferenza</title>
<script src="utils.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

Inserire i dati richiesti:<br><br>
<form method="post" action="input.php">
<b> Richiedente Conferenza:</b><br><br>
Nome:<input type="text" name="nome" size="20"><br>
Cognome:<input type="text" name="cognome" size="20"><br>
Email: <input type="email" name="email" size="20"><br>
Oggetto Conferenza:<br><textarea name="oggetto" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Specificare oggetto Videoconferenza"></textarea><br>
<select class="date" name="day">
                        <option value="1">01
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">02
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">03
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">04
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">05
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">06
                        </option>
                        <option value="7">07
                        </option>
                        <option value="8">08
                        </option>
                        <option value="9">09
                        </option>
                        <option value="10">10
                        </option>
                        <option value="11">11
                        </option>
                        <option value="12">12
                        </option>
                        <option value="13">13
                        </option>
                        <option value="14">14
                        </option>
                        <option value="15">15
                        </option>
                        <option value="16">16
                        </option>
                        <option value="17">17
                        </option>
                        <option value="18">18
                        </option>
                        <option value="19">19
                        </option>
                        <option value="20">20
                        </option>
                        <option value="21">21
                        </option>
                        <option value="22">22
                        </option>
                        <option value="23">23
                        </option>
                        <option value="24">24
                        </option>
                        <option value="25">25
                        </option>
                        <option value="26">26
                        </option>
                        <option value="27">27
                        </option>
                        <option value="28">28
                        </option>
                        <option value="29">29
                        </option>
                        <option value="30">30
                        </option>
                        <option value="31">31
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="month">
                        <option value="1">January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">June
                        </option>
                        <option value="7">July
                        </option>
                        <option value="8">August
                        </option>
                        <option value="9">September
                        </option>
                        <option value="10">October
                        </option>
                        <option value="11">November
                        </option>
                        <option value="12">December
                        </option>
                    </select>   
<br>
<b>Partecipanti </b>
<br>
<br>
<div id="start">
    <div id="first">
      Nome:<input type="text" name="nomep[]" size="20"><br> 
      Cognome: <input type="text" name="cognomep[]" size="20"><br> 
      Email: <input type="email" name="emailp[]" size="20"><br>
      Personale:
       <select name="tipologia[]" required="required">
                <option>Interno</option>
                <option>Esterno</option>
       </select>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
 Numero partecipanti interni:
 <input type="text" id="n1" size="1" value="1"><br>

 <button><a href="#" id="add">Aggiungi partecipante</a></button>


<input type="submit" value="Invia" > 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**input.php**

```
<?php
//Connecting to db here

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456789";
$dbname = "Project1";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

// Richiedente
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$oggetto = $_POST['oggetto'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];

// Personale
$nomep = $_POST['nomep'];
$cognomep = $_POST['cognomep'];
$emailp = $_POST['emailp'];
$tipologia = $_POST['tipologia'];

//inserting data order
$query1 = "INSERT INTO Prenotazione (nome,cognome,email,oggetto,day,month) VALUES ('$nome','$cognome','$email','$oggetto', $day, $month)";
//execute the query here
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1 ); //if you are using pg_query and $conn is the connection resource
// Interni
$query = "";
if( !empty( $_POST['nomep'] ) ) {

    foreach( $_POST['nomep'] as $key => $nomep ) {

        $cognomep = empty( $_POST[$key]['cognomep'] ) ? NULL : $_POST[$key]['cognomep'];
        $emailp = empty( $_POST[$key]['emailp'] ) ? NULL : $_POST[$key]['emailp'];
        $tipologia = empty( $_POST[$key]['tipologia'] ) ? NULL : $_POST[$key]['tipologia'];
        $query .= " ( '$nomep', '$cognomep', '$emailp','$tipologia', '$email', '$oggetto' ) ";
    }
}
if( !empty( $query ) ) {

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO Personale (nomep, cognomep, emailp, tipologia, email_rich,oggetto_rich) VALUES ".$query;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query2 ); //
}

?>
```

**utils.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function(){

      var val1 =$("#n1").val();
      for(var i=0;i<val1;i++){
      $("#start").append($("#first").clone());
      }
    });
});
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8GPI.png)

Comment: Step through your code line by line, think about what each line does. For example, what is `$_POST[$key]` going to be?

Comment: You need a comma after every `values` grouping e.g. `VALUES (...) (...)` is invalid SQL. This also is insecure, you are open to SQL injections. The queries should be parameterized. I also would just execute one `insert` at a time in the `for` loop.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: The second set of data you fetch (where the names end with `[]`) will be an array in the format `['cognomep' => ['first', 'second', ...], 'emailp' => ['first', 'second', ...], etc]` so `$_POST[$key]['cognomep']` should be `$_POST['cognomep'][$key]`. That goes for all those values.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you for the reply! I have tried what you suggest to me and it works! But if add  new fields, ( so if i click on " aggiungi Partecipante " ) with a js file so it creates new fields with nomep,cognomep,emailp i can't insert these in the database.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue as long as they too have `[]` after the names and exist in the same form.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes with the botton "aggiungi Partecipante" i recreate the same fields ( so they have [] ) but if i create for example 2 of these i can't insert them to the database ( 
I hope I managed to explain, in case I can upload an image )

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue. I would recommend that you create a new question for that, including the HTML markup (the complete form), the JS code that creates the form fields and also the result of `var_dump($_POST)` when you post the form. You should also include if you post the form using Ajax (if yes, that code should be included as well) or if it's an "ordinary" form post.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The problem is that i can't insert a dynamic form into the database. I update the first post with the js code and the image. 
maybe this way I can be clearer

Comment: I got that. But that's not what this question was about so I suggest you to create a new question for that issue with all the information I stated in my previous comment. Without that info, we would just be wildly guessing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ok, thanks for your help! You help me a lot :)

Comment: @Kepz23 little note, since in this question you stated that the problem was solved, mind posting the answer of your question yourself and mark it as answered.

Comment: @killstreet 
In reality it is not completely resolved, also because the real problem of the title, ie the insertion of a dynamic form does not work yet :(

Comment: @Kepz23 I posted an answer in your newer question on whats wrong with the code.

Comment: I saw, thank you :)